# Why does calling a Bash command from Ruby throw an error?

Tags: ruby, directory

I'm attempting to execute the following bash command on some images using Ruby:

```
class Pingcrush
  def initialize
    Dir.foreach('drawable') do |item|
      next if item == '.' or item == '..'
      # do work on real items
      if item.end_with?(".png") then
        %x["wine pngcrush.exe -brute drawable/#{item} new/#{item}"]
      end
    end
  end
end
Pingcrush.new
```

The directory I am in is the parent to both `drawable` and `new`, however, when when I attempt to run the script I always get the same error:

```
sh: wine pngcrush.exe -brute drawable/feed_cl.png new/feed_cl.png: not found
```

Why is this happening? I tried switching around the path I'm calling in Ruby and can't seem to make this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its executing your shell but can't find wine. Try setting the full path to where wine is installed.

```
which wine
```

Comment: @Aidanc, you should give the full path for wine and your exe file (pngcrush.exe).

Answer (score 1):

Don't put quotes around your command.

Answer (score 1):

You have checked that `wine pngcrush.exe -brute drawable/feed_cl.png new/feed_cl.png` works when you type it from the command line, haven't you?